# MySQL Export Data

Tags: mysql

I am having some problem when trying to export database from MySQL workbench. I've been researched for few hours but no luck. When I click on the manage import/export it prompt an error message. The error message reads:

> Error starting workbench admin RunTimeError: Could not initialize WMI
>   interface: Could not connect to target machine.

I wonder what's wrong with it. Thanks in advance. My current version is 5.6.11

Comment: What OS do you have? I have solved a few issues before by simply reinstalling the Workbench.

Comment: What is OS ? Window 7 ?

Comment: @CostisAivalis Hello you there?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 is an OS (Operating System). Is that the one you have?

Comment: @Patrick Yes it's window 7

Comment: I had no issues with Win7. Only with Ubuntu and that was a while back. Did you try to reinstall?

Comment: I cannot though. If I reinstall all my database will be gone right?

Comment: Nothing will be gone. Your database runs as a different process.